# Adding GeoPandas Dataframe to PostGIS table?

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas

I have a simple GeoPandas Dataframe:

[image]

I would like to upload this GeoDataframe to a PostGIS table. I have a Database setup with the PostGIS extension already but can't seem to add this Dataframe as a table.

I have tried the following:

```
engine = <>
meta = MetaData(engine)
eld_test = Table('eld_test', meta, Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), Column('key_comb_drvr', Text), 
                 Column('geometry', Geometry('Point', srid=4326))) 
eld_test.create(engine) 
conn = engine.connect() 
conn.execute(eld_test.insert(), df.to_dict('records'))
```

Comment: I have tried the following:

engine = <>

# create table
meta = MetaData(engine)
eld_test = Table('eld_test', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('key_comb_drvr', Text),
    Column('geometry', Geometry('Point', srid=4326))
)
eld_test.create(engine)

# DBAPI's executemany with list of dicts
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(eld_test.insert(), df.to_dict('records'))

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, please have a read of our [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)! Could you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/239198/edit) your post to include your code posted in the comments?

Answer (score 41):

Using Panda's [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method and [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) you can store a dataframe in Postgres. And since you're storing a Geodataframe, [GeoAlchemy](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will handle the geom column for you. 
Here's a code sample:

```
# Imports
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry, WKTElement
from sqlalchemy import *
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

# Creating SQLAlchemy's engine to use
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@host:socket/database')


geodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.DataFrame.from_csv('<your dataframe source>'))
#... [do something with the geodataframe]

geodataframe['geom'] = geodataframe['geometry'].apply(lambda x: WKTElement(x.wkt, srid=<your_SRID>)

#drop the geometry column as it is now duplicative
geodataframe.drop('geometry', 1, inplace=True)

# Use 'dtype' to specify column's type
# For the geom column, we will use GeoAlchemy's type 'Geometry'
geodataframe.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False, 
                         dtype={'geom': Geometry('POINT', srid= <your_srid>)})
```

Worth noting that 'if_exists' parameter allows you to handle the way the dataframe will be added to your postgres table:

```
    if_exists = replace: If table exists, drop it, recreate it, and insert data.
    if_exists = fail: If table exists, do nothing.
    if_exists = append: If table exists, insert data. Create if does not exist.
```

Comment: Is there an opportunity to reproject here by specifying a different SRID than the one in the geometry column, or does the current SRID have to be used? Also [what is  the best way to get the integer SRID from the geometry column](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350870/getting-geometry-column-integer-srid-from-a-geopandas-geodataframe)?

Comment: Why using this method I have sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine error?

Comment: keep in mind that this approach assumes that all your 'geoms' are actually populated with objects - so if None types (or some other non-geom) occupies any records, an error will be thrown. great approach provided by @Hamri Said!

Comment: I think it is worth noting here that this will NOT work if you are using a `psycopg2.connection` instead of an `sqlalchemy.engine` object, even though in many other cases the two are effectively interchangeable.

Answer (score 11):

As of [recently](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/1248), `geopandas` has a [`to_postgis` method](https://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=to_postgis#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis). Woohoo!

**Note:** you will need `psycopg2-binary`, `sqlalchemy2`, and `geoalchemy2` installed.

```py
import geopandas
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Set up database connection engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@host:5432/')

# Load data into GeoDataFrame, e.g. from shapefile
geodata = geopandas.read_file("shapefile.shp")

# GeoDataFrame to PostGIS
geodata.to_postgis(
    con=engine,
    name="table_name"
)
```

Comment: Do you know about the CRS? how to add the CRS for the data?

Comment: Have you already set the CRS on the geodata? https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/projections.html#setting-a-projection

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the solution.

Comment: I'm getting this error: InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.RaiseException) find_srid() - could not find the corresponding SRID - is the geometry registered in the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table?  Is there an uppercase/lowercase mismatch?
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function find_srid(character varying,character varying,character varying) line 17 at RAIS
[SQL: SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'habitation', 'geometry');]

Comment: @NikhilVJ, it looks like PostGIS doesn't recognize the spatial reference for the data. What is the SRID of your source data?

Comment: Solved by using this in table creation: `geometry GEOMETRY (GEOMETRY, 4326) NULL`  earlier I was just doing `geometry GEOMETRY NULL` as my data is heterogeneous and I didn't know there was a catch-all "GEOMETRY" I could use instead of LINESTRING etc - and owing to that I wasn't setting the SRID in the table.

Answer (score 6):

I have also had the same question you've asked and have spent many, many days on it (more than I care to admit) looking for a solution.  Assuming the following postgreSQL table with the postGIS extension,

```
postgres=> \d cldmatchup.geo_points;
Table "cldmatchup.geo_points"
Column   |         Type         |                               Modifiers                                
-----------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
gridid    | bigint               | not null default nextval('cldmatchup.geo_points_gridid_seq'::regclass)
lat       | real                 | 
lon       | real                 | 
the_point | geography(Point,4326) | 

Indexes:
"geo_points_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gridid)
```

this is what I *finally* got working:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from geoalchemy2 import Geography, Geometry
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from shapely.geometry import Point
from psycopg2.extensions import adapt, register_adapter, AsIs

# From http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-types but 
# modified to accomodate postGIS point type rather than a postgreSQL 
# point type format
def adapt_point(point):
    from psycopg2.extensions import adapt, AsIs
    x = adapt(point.x).getquoted()
    y = adapt(point.y).getquoted()
    return AsIs("'POINT (%s %s)'" % (x, y))

register_adapter(Point, adapt_point)

engine = create_engine('postgresql://<yourUserName>:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres', echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
meta = MetaData(engine, schema='cldmatchup')

# Create reference to pre-existing "geo_points" table in schema "cldmatchup"
geoPoints = Table('geo_points', meta, autoload=True, schema='cldmatchup', autoload_with=engine)

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'lat':[45.15, 35., 57.], 'lon':[-35, -150, -90.]})

# Create a shapely.geometry point 
the_point = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.lon, df.lat)]

# Create a GeoDataFrame specifying 'the_point' as the column with the 
# geometry data
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.copy(), crs=crs, geometry=the_point)

# Rename the geometry column to match the database table's column name.
# From https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/geopandas/latest/geopandas.pdf,
# Section 1.2.2 p 7
geo_df = geo_df.rename(columns{'geometry':'the_point'}).set_geometry('the_point')

# Write to sql table 'geo_points'
geo_df.to_sql(geoPoints.name, engine, if_exists='append', schema='cldmatchup', index=False)

session.close()
```

I can't say if my database connection logic is the best since I basically copied that from another link and was just happy that I was able to successfully automap (or reflect) my existing table with the geometry definition recognized.  I've  been writing python to sql spatial code for only a few months, so I know there is much to learn.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution which is requires only psycopg2 and shapely (in addition geopandas of course). It is generally bad practice to iterate through `(Geo)DataFrame` objects because it is slow, but for small ones, or for one-off tasks, it will still get the job done.

Basically it works by dumping the geometry to WKB format in another column and then re-casts it to `GEOMETRY` type when inserting.

Note that you will have to create the table ahead of time with the right columns.

```
import psycopg2 as pg2
from shapely.wkb import dumps as wkb_dumps
import geopandas as gpd


# Assuming you already have a GeoDataFrame called "gdf"...

# Copy the gdf if you want to keep the original intact
insert_gdf = gdf.copy()

# Make a new field containing the WKB dumped from the geometry column, then turn it into a regular 
insert_gdf["geom_wkb"] = insert_gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda x: wkb_dumps(x))

# Define an insert query which will read the WKB geometry and cast it to GEOMETRY type accordingly
insert_query = """
    INSERT INTO my_table (id, geom)
    VALUES (%(id)s, ST_GeomFromWKB(%(geom_wkb)s));
"""

# Build a list of execution parameters by iterating through the GeoDataFrame
# This is considered bad practice by the pandas community because it is slow.
params_list = [
    {
        "id": i,
        "geom_wkb": row["geom_wkb"]
    } for i, row in insert_gdf.iterrows()
]

# Connect to the database and make a cursor
conn = pg2.connect(host=<your host>, port=<your port>, dbname=<your dbname>, user=<your username>, password=<your password>)
cur = conn.cursor()

# Iterate through the list of execution parameters and apply them to an execution of the insert query
for params in params_list:
    cur.execute(insert_query, params)
conn.commit()
```