# Having 'can't adapt type 'Point' error when try to load data from local to PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geopandas, geoalchemy

I am trying to load this shapefile into the PostgreSQL database.
Here is what data looks like:

first, read the file

```
data_path = "./RFSNSW_BFPL"
rfsnw_bfpl= gpd.read_file( os.path.join(data_path, "RFSNSW_BFPL.shp") )
```

[image]

then, I am trying to  create schema in the database

```
conn.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rfsnw_bfpl")
rfsnw_bfpl_schema = '''CREATE TABLE rfsnw_bfpl (
                     category NUMERIC, 
                     shape_leng NUMERIC, 
                     shape_area NUMERIC, 
                     geom GEOMETRY(POINT,4283))''' 

conn.execute(rfsnw_bfpl_schema)
```

Here, I try to change one column's name.

```
srid = 4283
rfsnw_bfplWkCpy = rfsnw_bfpl.copy()
rfsnw_bfplWkCpy['geom'] = rfsnw_bfpl['geometry']
rfsnw_bfplWkCpy = rfsnw_bfplWkCpy.drop(columns="geometry")
```

[image]

Lastly, when I try to load my data to database, it shows me 'can't adapt type 'Point''

```
rfsnw_bfplWkCpy_table_name = "rfsnw_bfplWkCpy"
rfsnw_bfplWkCpy.to_sql(rfsnw_bfplWkCpy_table_name, conn, if_exists='append', index=False, 
                         dtype={'geom': Geometry(geometry_type='POINT', srid= 4283)})
```

Here is the screenshot of the error
[image]

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325415/writing-geopandas-data-frame-to-postgis

Comment: Other related too :) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239198/adding-geopandas-dataframe-to-postgis-table

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but a way to do it another simple way.

You do not need to manually manage dropping table if exists or to create yourself the table structure with an SQL CREATE statement. If your type are correctly defined at geodataframe level, geopandas will create and replace the table if it exists using correct types without manual intervention.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

gdf = gpd.read_file('/path/to/points.shp')
print(gdf.crs.srs) # To check your CRS, optional

# Lower column names. You may not want it. If so, comment below line
gdf.columns = map(str.lower, gdf.columns)

# Rename column geometry
gdf = gdf.rename(columns={'geometry':'geom'}).set_geometry('geom')

engine = create_engine("postgres://user:password@host:port/databasename")  
gdf.to_postgis("my_table_name_destination", engine, if_exists='replace')
```