# Getting geometry column integer SRID from a GeoPandas geodataframe?

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, srid, geodataframe

The primary answer to [Adding GeoPandas Dataframe to PostGIS table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239198/adding-geopandas-dataframe-to-postgis-table/246090) requires entering the `geodataframe` `geometry` column's integer SRID.

Getting the CRS attribute using the `crs` attribute like so

```
import geopandas as gpd
file_path = 'my_geodata.shp'

gdf = gpd.read_file(file_path)
geom_srid = gdf.geometry.crs['init']
```

gives a string like `'epsg:32616'`.

The integer value can be extracted using regex:

```
geom_srid_num = re.search(r'\d+$', geom_srid)
```

But I'm not sure if the SRID is written in this format all the time, and if this method is reliable. Is there a more appropriate way to retrieve the integer SRID for a `geodataframe` `geometry` column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `geopandas` <= v0.6.3., `gdf.crs` returns a dictionary like `{'init': 'epsg:EPSG_CODE'}`. So, more appropriate way is to use tools of `geopandas` defined in `geopandas.tools` module.

```
geom_srid_num  = gpd.tools.crs.epsg_from_crs(gdf.crs)
print(geom_srid_num) # OUT: 32616 -> int
```

**EDIT:** As @snowman2 states in comment, `epsg_from_crs` is deprecated in **`geopandas` v0.7.0**. In this version `gdf.crs` returns `pyproj.crs.CRS` instance. Thus, the most appropriate way is to use `to_epsg()` method of CRS class.

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(file_path)
geom_srid_num  = gdf.crs.to_epsg()
print(geom_srid_num) # OUT: 32616 -> int
```

Comment: That method is currently deprecated in geopandas master - will be version 0.7.0. I would recommend updating your suggestion following this logic: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/9e45a12bcf114e13fc530ce9ff8a7eb533c9de86/geopandas/tools/crs.py#L47-L52

Comment: @snowman2 I've updated the answer. Thank you for your warning. I've updated my knowledge, too. I will update the answer when v0.7.0 is released.

Comment: I was using geopandas 0.4.0, which didn't have the newer method but it's good to know that it exists in the current version.