# python - psycopg2.errors.RaiseException find_srid() - could not find the corresponding SRID

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geopandas, psycopg2

I'm trying to import a layer into a PostGIS database with

```
gdf.to_postgis('test_polygons', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'geom': Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid= 4326)})
```

And I'm getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1276, in _execute_context
> self.dialect.do_execute(   File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py",
> line 609, in do_execute
> cursor.execute(statement, parameters) psycopg2.errors.RaiseException: find_srid() - could not find the
> corresponding SRID - is the geometry registered in the
> GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table?  Is there an uppercase/lowercase mismatch?
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function find_srid(character varying,character
> varying,character varying) line 17 at RAISE

I have a custom projection, which i set to the layer
Any ideas, what's wrong with geometry and srid?

Full error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1276, in _execute_context
> self.dialect.do_execute(   File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py",
> line 609, in do_execute
> cursor.execute(statement, parameters) psycopg2.errors.RaiseException: find_srid() - could not find the
> corresponding SRID - is the geometry registered in the
> GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table?  Is there an uppercase/lowercase mismatch?
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function find_srid(character varying,character
> varying,character varying) line 17 at RAISE

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#84>", line 1, in
>
> gdf.to_postgis('test_polygons', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'geom': Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid=
> 4326)})   File
> "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py",
> line 1097, in to_postgis
> geopandas.io.sql._write_postgis(   File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\sql.py",
> line 375, in _write_postgis
> target_srid = connection.execute(   File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1003, in execute
> return self.*execute_text(object*, multiparams, params)   File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1172, in _execute_text
> ret = self._execute_context(   File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1316, in _execute_context
> self.*handle_dbapi_exception(   File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1510, in *handle_dbapi_exception
> util.raise*(   File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py",
> line 182, in raise*
> raise exception   File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1276, in _execute_context
> self.dialect.do_execute(   File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py",
> line 609, in do_execute
> cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.RaiseException)
> find_srid() - could not find the corresponding SRID - is the geometry
> registered in the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table?  Is there an
> uppercase/lowercase mismatch? CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function
> find_srid(character varying,character varying,character varying) line
> 17 at RAISE
>
> [SQL: SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'test_polygons', 'geometry');]
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/2j85)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the function to_postgis works seems to look for the srid in your geometry, not the `dtype` argument (see `_write_postgis` [here](https://github.com/HTenkanen/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/io/sql.py)), so maybe it's the problem.

Does your input geometry have a correct srid? Did you created it for example like that:

```
# Create a GeoDataFrame specifying 'the_point' as the column with the 
# geometry data
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.copy(), crs=crs, geometry=the_point)
```

Maybe look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239198/adding-geopandas-dataframe-to-postgis-table) for a working example (I took the above code there)

Comment: Yes, the problem was that srid was not 4326. so, when i changed it to 4326, .to_postgis() method worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, which was from a bug in geopandas where it only looks at the `geometry_columns` and not the `geography_columns` table for the SRID.

See: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/2096#issuecomment-1814923034

The (very very hacky) way I fixed this in my upload script was to insert rows manually to get around the fix. You can also use 'replace' instead of 'append', but I wanted to preserve the table.

```py
conn.exec_driver_sql(f"INSERT INTO public.geometry_columns (f_table_catalog,f_table_schema,f_table_name,f_geometry_column,coord_dimension,srid,type) "
+ f"VALUES ('postgres','{schema}','{table_name}','geometry',2,4326,'GEOMETRY');"
            )
gdf_reprojected.to_postgis(
                table_name,
                conn,
                schema=schema,
                if_exists="replace",
                index=False,
                dtype={"geometry": Geography("GEOMETRY", srid=4326)})
conn.exec_driver_sql(f"delete from public.geometry_columns where f_table_schema = '{schema}' and f_table_name = '{table_name}';")
```